# How to Print Object Line by line

Tags: java, eclipse, object, text

I have the following code:

```
 in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D/sample.txt"));
  String str;   
  while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) 
  {  
      process(str);
  }
```

Say sample.txt contains 'n' number of lines. I am passing the String object to another function process in the same class.The function process contains following code:

```
public void process(String s) {
String elements = s;
System.out.println(elements);
```

How can i print only the first line or the line that i wish to be printed. Please help.

Comment: Which line do you wish to be printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, you could pass in the lineCount - that is

```
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/sample.txt")); // <-- added ':'
String str;   
int lineCount = 0;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {  
  process(str, lineCount++);
}
```

And then

```
public void process(String s, int lineCount) {
  if (lineCount == 0) { // <-- only the first line.
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a flag to your process method to advise it to print or not. Something like this:

```
public void process(String s, boolean print) {
String elements = s;
if(print)
   System.out.println(elements);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a counter to your loop, and only call process on the lines you want to process.

```
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D/sample.txt"));
String str;   
int readLines = 0;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) 
{   
    readLines++;
    if(readLines == 1) //Only process first line
     process(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `process(str)` only for the line you wish:

```
int lineToPrint = 1;

in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D/sample.txt"));
  String str;   
  int i =1;
  while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) 
  {  
     if (i==1){
         process(str);
     }
     i++;
  }
```